# Kendo UI Scheduler - setting slotTemplate after data received from server

Tags: asynchronous, kendo-ui, typescript, angular, kendo-scheduler

In the 'navigation' event of the scheduler I am getting data from a server for the new date.
I have a function that is called from slotTemplate of the day view that uses the data received to color the scheduler slots.

I use Angular2, TypeScript and Reactive-Extensions/RxJS Observable to receive the answer from the server.

My problem is that when I navigate to another date, the slotTemplate function is being run before the answer from the server is processed so the data isn't available for coloring the slots.
Sure enough, after the data is ready, the slotTemplate function isn't being run again.

I would much prefer to use Kendo's built-in methods, if possible, and less jQuery, to solve this issue.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Don't make it observable, maybe?

Comment: Is that a question or an answer? :)
How would it solve the problem? How would it help?

Comment: Hope that didn't come off as rude, I meant it as an actual question...

Observables are there to stay. It's not up to me.
But if it was, how do you suggest I do it?
The request to the server is asynchronous after all...

Comment: your http.get () request can take a  http.get ().subscribe(..) function, why not run your slotTemplate() inside subscribe()?

Comment: I'm not the one running slotTemplate, it's a field in the KendoSchedulerOptions object.
When the Kendo scheduler builds its table, it calls the function I provided to slotTemplate and incorporates the result string between the <td></td> tags of the scheduler table cell.

Comment: Observables also have the subscribe() method but I can't use it since the scheduler will be built and slotTemplate executed before the callback function I provided the subscribe() with will be executed (same goes for http.get().subscribe, which Observables might even use internally).

Comment: In your subscribe function you could call the refresh function: `var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.refresh();`

Comment: Nope, the view isn't refreshed.

Comment: Solved: Resetting the view to it's current value redraws the scheduler.
`let scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");`
`scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: Resetting the view to it's current value redraws the scheduler.

When the Observable returns you can color the scheduler's slots or do any other change to the DOM and then re-set the view and the changes will be shown.

The code to re-set the view is:

```
let scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.view(scheduler.viewName());
```